# Google MAP Navigation for android to get driving directions

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, android-2.3-gingerbread, directions

[image]i am working on google map navigation for android . for 2.3 android version .

i searched on google found some examples but not sure showing all errors . .all are showing same errors .. here i am posting the one last i tried

https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0MdROeR0jbvWVVNUV9jbk1OeEE

check the above code and test on 2.3.3 ... is that working or not.

my logcat information  is

```
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at app.akexorcist.googlemapsv2direction.Main.onCreate(Main.java:27)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-21 13:46:53.219: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I can't download your file right now, but I can tell you the answer is in the 2nd line of those errors. It can't find the class you are trying to pull all this info from. So all the methods, variables etc are spitting out all the errors below that 2nd line. Basically saying "hey! where is all this stuff?!" I could attempt to help you if you posted the code for that com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

Comment: @IrishWhiskey - https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0MdROeR0jbvWVVNUV9jbk1OeEE

Comment: @Devandar sorry bud, I can't download anything right now. I think the guys answering are right though, it looks like you're missing some library's, imports, etc.

Comment: @IrishWhiskey - ok , if you found any working example please post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you did not import `google play services library` because it is looking for a `styleable` resource

Comment: imported google play library in to workspace - if you have imported already please give me a screenshot of Prrojects javabuild path --> android dependecis

Comment: you cannot import just the jar file, you need to import the while project and use that as a library project

Comment: yes i used same - is there any jar in side bin foldelr for google play services

Comment: if you import google play services as a library project you dont need to worry about any jars inside the project. look at Divya Motiwala's answer to make sure you did it right

Comment: yes i did same but on android dependencies showing on file missing

Comment: To solve that problem I had to completely remove the library from the project and from disk then re-download it from the SDK Manager and go through the whole process again, I think its something with the new ADT

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you not add the google play services project into your Eclipse workspace and after need to add the dependency to Google Play Services into your project GoogleMapsV2Direction
check this:

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

for me this project works

Comment: Google Apis Android API 10 revision 2

Comment: into SDK manager in folder 2.3.3(Api 10) select Google Apis and download it, then create new project and target SDK wiht Google APis 10 then in new project copy folder scr and  res and AndroidManifest.xml from GoogleMapsV2Direction  after do waht i said in my response and it works for me

Comment: please provide me your source code as example to me  - i am new to android .. please help me

Comment: my version of cell is 2.3.3 where i test it

Comment: my application also targeted to 2.3.3 only

Comment: U do this?  http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/reference-library.png

Comment: i am sorry
I'm at work and I have some things blocked in Internet 
no can see pic. but it project works i download from your link and it steps i said,  only i changed in code was manifest the key for i can see map

Answer (score 0):

You might not have imported required libraries for it.

Check [this](http://divyamotiwala.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-google-maps-part-1-loading-map.html) if you need help on how to import google-play-services to project,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you haven't included any libraries as projects on the Java Build Path. That's taken care of in the Android tab now. If that doesn't work, try checking more choices in the Java Build Path -> Order and Export.